# Azure API Management product subscription tracking

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using `Azure API Management` for managing our APIs. Its containing product and all. Now I also want to catch some of the customer information into my database.

So my question is : "**Is there anyway such that whenever someone is subscribing any product, my API will trigger?**"

What I want to do is I will create an API which will fetch the details from Azure via REST API for all subscriptions and I want to call (auto trigger) that API whenever someone subscribe any product successfully. I know we can set the *Approval workflow*, we can *send notification email* also to any specific email id, but can we call any HTTP request?

Also if anyone have more idea about Developer portal then please share. (can we customize it, till what level, how, etc.)

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put an **Event Grid system topic** on the resource group containing **API Management service** with

- filter for `Resource Write Success`
- subject filter / Subject begins with `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{apiManagementService}/subscriptions`

and forward to **Azure Function** or WebHook - basically filter for activities logged as `Subscribe to product or Update subscription` on the resource.

Comment: I was busy with some other things.. but I am looking into your option.. will update here once done.. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for very late reply.. I have tested this.. when I Subscribe from APIM then this function is triggering but when user subscribe from developer portal then this function is not triggering.. Can you explain me how can I decide this Subject filter??

Comment: You are right. I did not test with portal unfortunately. Problem is that there is not even a resource action logged then a user subscribes over developer portal. Hence it is not a matter of filtering.

Comment: Actually it may be because it is not logging when someone subscribe from Developer Portal. here is an bug on github also https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/1208